# Display total count number of view all node create by user

Tags: 7, views, nodes

how can i create views of number of total viewed statistic of all node by create by user.
for example:

uid=1
total:2500
today:500
yesterday:1000
last week: 5000
last month: 15000

Answer (score 1):

[Node View Count](https://drupal.org/project/nodeviewcount) module allows to **count node views**. It records each view of node with user uid and time-stamp. So now you can know how many times a user viewed node by day, week, month and etc.

You can integrate this module with views and you can use it to create different statistics pages, output new not viewed nodes for user and many more.